# Installation Error on paramiko package 1.4.1 on mac

Tags: python, ssh, cryptography, paramiko

I was recently trying to run a piece of code with paramiko, the code is simply building a basic ssh port and the code is available on other machines. However, when I install paramiko and run the code on my own machine, it's not working. I double checked the code to make sure it's the same. Then I checked the Error when compiling, it says:

```
    import paramiko
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 33, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
  TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I seeked online for answers and it said the possible problem I might have is that I don't have the crypto 1.4.1 package. Therefore, I use pip to install the package and for some reason I received the same error as running the program.

```
pip install crypto
Collecting crypto
  Using cached crypto-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting shellescape (from crypto)
  Using cached shellescape-3.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Naked (from crypto)
  Using cached Naked-0.1.31-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from Naked->crypto)
  Using cached requests-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyyaml (from Naked->crypto)
  Using cached PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So does anyone know what's going on with my machine? Is there any other packages I need to install before I install crypto?

I'm currently using mac OS Y Yosemite and my pip is upgraded.

*************************update*****************************

This is the original code:

```
import threading
import paramiko
import subprocess

def ssh_command(ip,user,passwd,command):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(ip,username = user, password = passwd)
    ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()
    if ssh_session.active:
        ssh_session.exec_command(command)
        print ssh_session.recv(1024)
    return

ssh_command('192.168.100.301','GLZ','TripleBody','id')
```

Hopefully this will help!

Also about the version problem, I just tried using pip to install pycrypto(which is version 2.6.1) and the same error raises.

Thanks for your great help and patience in advance,
Peter

Comment: have you tried installed the latest version of crypto? it is 2.6.1

Comment: could you also provide the code?

Comment: I just edited the problem and hopefully this will help~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I got the same problem.
I tried the following instruction and it works! (Courtesy of ptmcg from https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12722&history=1)

> This line in requirements.py of the packaging module:

```
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
```

uses a feature that was introduced in pyparsing 2.0.2, specifically the use of "expr()" to copy an expression, in this case "MARKER_EXPR()". Upgrading to pyparsing 2.1.10 (latest version) is the recommended course of action, but this can also be fixed by changing the code in requirements.py to:

```
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR)("marker")
```

(In this line, it is not actually necessary to make a copy of MARKER_EXPR.)

Comment: Hello PetaGlz.. if my answer helps you would you mind giving me an upvote? Thanks!

Comment: sorry sir, I'm not pretty familar with stack overflow and I didn't check my account real often. When I was trying to give you a upvote, it says I can't, sorry again for that.